# Recreating the FTDI configuration with wireshark

Tags: serial-port, usb, wireshark, ftdi

I would like to write a linux driver for a piece of hardware that has an FTDI (0403:6001) built in. There is a driver for Windows.
I was able to sniff the usb-traffic using wireshark and a virtual machine. Like this, I could filter out the serial messages sent, but don't know how to configure baudrate etc. Also, the default values from pyserial do not work.

Is there a way to read out the configuration of the FTDI from the USB sniffs?

Comment: Is this information [FTDI SIO, 8U232AM and 245 Linux USB serial driver](http://ftdi-usb-sio.sourceforge.net/) useful?

Comment: the FTDI chip does work and is recognized as /dev/ttyUSB0.. I just don't know how to configure it. I do see that the device gets answers like "03 01 05", but I cannot reconstruct this using pyserial.

Comment: In that case, FTDI is interface chip, so it will be meaningless to look at USB data. It is necessary to monitor and analyze the serial data between the FTDI chip and the connected device.

Comment: But doesn't the interface chip also need some kind of configuration? and to analyze the serial data between the ftdi chip and the connected device I would need to know configuration such as baudrate, wouldn't I? Also the chip is within the hardware somewhere..

Comment: Currently, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, no parity is used in most cases. The baudrate will be 5 patterns from 1,200 to 9,600, even at high up to 19,200. I guess that it will not take so long if you try everything. If it is not such a general specification and this question is the continuation of your previous question(undocumented button), it is better to ask a question on a forum dealing with hardware Q&A. If you ask with manufacturer's name, model number, size, dimensions, appearance and board photo as much as possible, you may be able to obtain  the document or specification of the device.

Comment: In the end I figured it out: they did not use a clear text protocol, but used the rts/cts and dtr/dts signals for communication..(just 4 states) took me long enought to figure that out..

Answer (score 1):

when an FTDI is attached to linux machine the kernel modules `ftdi_sio` and `usbserial` are loaded

source code is in https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/usb/serial/ftdi_sio.c and https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/usb/serial

if you want to talk to the FTDI chips directly you can use the `libftdi` library on linux https://www.intra2net.com/en/developer/libftdi/

for sniffing the USB protocol communication of an FTDI chip with wireshark see this : https://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-bugs/201511/msg00579.html

you have to load `usbmon` kernel module for sniffing the FTDI https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB